# merge 2 values and put in a v-data-table column (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Is it possible to merge to values and put into one column in v-data-table?

***List.vue***

```
<template>
  <v-app>
        <v-data-table
          :items="items"
          :headers="headers"
        />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
         { first_name: "Peter", last_name: "Johnson" },
         { first_name: "Simon", last_name: "Walker" }
       ],
      headers: [
        { text: "first_name", value: "first_name" },
        { text: "last_name", value: "last_name" },
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

For example I want to put `Peter Johnson` in `Full name` column of my v-data-table, While it doesn't have `Full name` column.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can render a virtual column with the use of slots with `v-data-table`. But you need to have a column `full_name`.

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
  <template #item.full_name="{ item }">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</template>
</v-data-table>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { first_name: "Peter", last_name: "Johnson" },
        { first_name: "Simon", last_name: "Walker" }
      ],
      headers: [{ text: "Full Name", value: "full_name" }]
    };
  }
};
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#slots

Comment: If you're getting an ES lint error with the above you might want to try it in this format: `<template v-slot:[`item.full_name`]="{ item.first_name } { item.last_name }">`

Comment: Very bad approach, be carefull guys because filtering will no longer works when you do this

Comment: `#item.full_name` not works for me. I use `v-slot:item.full_name`

Answer (score 1):

On Pierre Said's answer,
'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier. (eslint-plugin-vue)

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:[`item.full_name`]="{ item }">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: May be `first_name` and `last_name` column are also shown in the table.

Answer (score -1):

just add a "fullname" virtual column on the back end, Or use a computed property.